# Block size invalid or too large - Failed to read Avro files

Tags: apache-spark, avro, spark-avro

I'm using spark and scala , and trying to read avro folders using 
com.databricks - spark-avro_2.11. All the folders were read successfully, except for one folder, which failed with the following exception. (attached)

I checked the files manually, and all of them seems ok and not corrupted. What could be the problem?

> Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.io.IOException:
>   Block size invalid or too large for this implementation: -26  at
>   org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.hasNextBlock(DataFileStream.java:275)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.hasNext(DataFileStream.java:197)

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: have u resolved this?